# Laravel : How to show a multiple rows from DB in one row in view blade

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-blade

In my Laravel project, I have a multiple rows in my DB table, similar to each other in every thing except ID, other column called stage

Stages table

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first |
| 2 | second |
| 3 | third |

subjects Table

| ID | name | stage_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 1 |
| 2 | English | 2 |
| 3 | English | 3 |

I need to show em in a blade like this

| # | name | stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | first, two, three, etc |

**I already have the relations in my modals, and I am already showing them in my blade by loop, but I just want to group the rows by name and show the different stages**

I hope that I explained the case well, I am not very good at explaining

**Updates : before editing I wrote a dummy data now I hope I explained the issue in more details**

The project idea is that you can create more than faculty
and every faculty has Stages and sections and every section has specialties and every specialty has subjects

now about subjects and stages
user can create subject like English and make it available to the first stage and 2nd and third ..etc ( the available stages in this faculty)

**The Stages belongs to Faculty**

**The Subjects belongs to Stage**

so the relations are

Subject Model

```
public function stage()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Stage::class);
}
```

Stage Model

```
    public function subjects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
}
```

Comment: Next question please include some code, it makes it easier to write up answers and don't have to assume everything.

Comment: why do you have same subject multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have "English" Multiple Times, you should have a subject Table :

Stages table

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first |
| 2 | second |
| 3 | third |

Subject table

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | English |

stage_subject Table :

| ID | stage_id | subject_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |

Subject Model

```
public function stage()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Stage::class);
}
```

Stage Model

```
    public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class);
}
```

Then in your foreach:

```
@php($subjects = Subject::with('stages')->get())

@foreach($subjects as $subject)
  {{ $subject->id }} | {{$subject->name}} | {{$subject->stages->pluck('name')->implode(', ')}}
@endforeach
```

If you don't / can't do a pivot table, then you can use collection :

```
@php($subjects = Subject::with('stages')->get())

@foreach($subjects->groupBy('name') as $name => $subjects)
  {{ $subjects->first()->id }} | {{$name}} | {{$subjects->pluck('stage.name')->implode(', ')}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I already did a pivot table, and it worked thank you,